# How to add placeholder in system.xml for custom admin configuration fields in magento 2

Tags: magento2, system.xml

I am creating field by using this code in my system.xml file of custom module

```
<field id="SenderCity" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Physical address</label>
    <validate>required-entry</validate>
</field>
```

The result of this code is as: 
[image] 

Now i want to add placeholder for that custom field. Should i use some custom JS or is there any tag for placeholder?

Comment: you need a placeholder or a default value?

Comment: need only placeholder

Comment: @iqbalmalik I think you can add comment to add field description. If you want placeholder then it would required additional customization. See my answer if you wants to add field description..

Answer (score 1):

Magento does not have tag file `<placeholder></placeholder>` for system.xml which will render as  `placeholder` HTML tag.

If you want to add a placeHolder folder button then you have to   create  `<frontend_model>` for this field.

See https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-system-configuration-elements-in-magento-2-0.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add comment to particular field, are you looking something like that?

```
<comment>Add your field description</comment>
```

So in your case, it would be like

```
<field id="SenderCity" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Physical address</label>
    <validate>required-entry</validate>
    <comment>Add your field description</comment>
</field>
```

Comment: i need placeholder not comment. comment shows under field but i am in need of placeholder inside field

Comment: Ok, in that case you can add default values which would be shown when no value is saved.. follow this article for more details http://magestandard.com/configure-default-field-values-magento-2/

Comment: see below xml files for further details vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/system.xml  and  vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/config.xml